# How can I recover Deleted files during Ubuntu setup, the drives are not there anymore

Tags: data-recovery, undelete, permanent-delete

I was using windows 7 32bit then it was showing some problems so I switched to Ubuntu and I accidentally deleted all my files on the hard disk during the Ubuntu setup....all those collection, pictures, videos and projects I had in my life is lost! Plzzz HELP ME!!!

Comment: Don't panic! You may get most (if not all) files back: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry. If you wiped and reformatted your drive, there is no way practical way outside of a laboratory to bring that back.

If it's any consolation, it's happened to each and every one of us at least once.

Best idea is to be very careful when installing a new operating system, and/or to keep extensive backups. Use two hard drives - one for media and documents, one for your system software and applications - is also a good idea.

Comment: You don't need two hard drives, two partitions can do the same thing. The only caveat is that you need to know a little bit about manual partitioning.

Comment: Yes, they can, and no, you don't. I haven't (needed to) use multiple disks instead of multiple partitions in years. But if you're accidentally wiping all your files when you install a new OS, I'm guessing you'd benefit from a simpler solution - one that doesn't mean needing to know about manual partitioning ;-)